# How to Detect Negative cycle in Bellman Ford Algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, bellman-ford

Following is my function used for implementing **bellman ford algorithm** for **detecting negative cycles in a graph** :

```
    int d[V]; // V is number of vertices in the graph, d[V] is the distance of the vertices from the source vertex

    vector<tuple<int,int,int>> edges; // defines edges as (u,v,w), where u and v are vertices and w is the weight b/w u and v

    int u,v,w;
    bool negativecycle_BF(int x){

        // x is the source vertex
        for(int i=1;i<=V;i++) d[i] = INF;

        d[x] = 0;

        for(int i=1;i<=V-1;i++){
            for(auto e:edges){
                tie(u,v,w) = e;
                d[v] = min(d[v], d[u]+w);  
            }
        }
        for(auto e: edges){
            tie(u,v,w) = e;
            if(d[v]>d[u]+w)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

My code only returns 0 no matter I have a negative cycle or not. Can someone point out that what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to define `u,w,v` outside the loop. You can just write `auto [u,v,w] = e;` inside both loops.

Comment: Will this work in the mentioned case? I've taken a vector of tuples as you can see. I tried this one but it gives an "unqualified-id before [ " error. It would be great if you can elaborate

Comment: You need a reasonably current C++ compiler; it's from the C++17 standard. Note that `e` is a single tuple from the vector `edges`, which is why `auto [u,v,w] = e;` works.

Comment: Oh, I'm still not aware of C++17 syntax completely. Seems like this would work as intended. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You've assigned `d[v]` with `min(d[v], d[u]+w)`, and then you check either `(d[v]>d[u]+w)`, which then never be true. Thus you always get `return false` which is `0` in **cpp**.

Btw, `for(auto e: edges){...}` is wrongly indented, so if you corrected, it'll help to understand the code easier.

Comment: I've indented it properly now. Also, as you can see, I'm going V-1 rounds first in which I'm calculating the shortest distances to all the other nodes from the source nodes and after that I'm running a last round on all the edges so that if there exists  a negative w, then the value will reduce further which it shouldn't.